# How to query different databases on different servers via JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, postgresql, jdbc

### Scenario

Given two different DBMS, e.g. a PostgreSQL on server ServerA and a MySQL on server ServerB. Each DBMS holds a database, say DatabaseA with table `A` and DatabaseB with table `B` respectively. A DBMS given above can be one of PostgreSQL, MySql, Oracle, H2 and even MongoDB or comparable hierarchical DMBS.

An example query (thus joining data from table A on ServerA (PostgreSQL) with data from table B on ServerB.

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B;
```

### Questions

- Is there any unifying JDBC "driver" around that fulfils the requirements?
- Apache Drill seems to be the alternative, but lacks stability and maturity right now. Any alternatives?
- What other ways are possible? A custom JDBC driver, doing statement analysis and routing to the different DBs?

Comment: You wouldn't do that through your application layer or web server. Instead you would probably want to look into setting up a DB Link between the two databases.

Comment: A DB Link between PostgreSQL and MySQL? How?

Comment: Look up DBI-Link, there are others. Just search google for `[DBMS]`-to-`[DBMS]` linking. (Where `[DBMS]` is whatever sql implementation you are looking for: i.e. `postgres-to-mysql linking`)

Comment: Ya right, all in the context of foreign data wrappers ..... what if the DBMS can be an arbitrary database (like H2, HSQLDB, etc.)? Will widen my question appropriately ...

Comment: In that case, yes you may be looking at writing a fairly complicated data layer that would basically be an implementation of LINQ for Java. This data layer would need to be able to keep a collection of open server connections you would need to create your initial "select"s against each individual server, then "join" them together in the data layer.

Comment: PostgreSQL's foreign data wrappers are probably one of the better options. Otherwise look into client-side joins in JDBC via wrapper drivers. "SQL/MED" is a good keyword to search for too.

Comment: @gmiley: Not sure, why you mention LINQ as it provides a programmatic layer for assembling queries (with type safety etc.) on top of SQL or similar. I do not want to alter the way I'm querying data, I want to stick to SQL.

Comment: @Craig: 1. Plz keep in mind, that I'm not focusing on PostgreSQL only: Any DMBS (with support via JDBC) should work. 2. Could you plz expand your answer? What stand MED for? JDBC wrapper drivers sounds promising ....

Comment: @MartinSenne So you want a JDBC proxy driver that can split up SQL, execute parts on multiple different DBMSes, and do client side joins to unify the results? Um. I don't rate your chances. I don't know if there's anything out there for that, but if there is I expect it'll cost $omgwtfbbq. You are going to need to be more flexible in how you approach this problem. As for SQL/MED - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/MED

Comment: @MartinSenne that is why I mentioned Linq. The vast number of DBMS' that you want to be able to support really makes anything other than an implementation similar to Linq nigh impossible, or at the very least so extremely complicated as to make it almost a lifelong project in itself. You would almost need a secondary data layer so your solution would look like this: `[UI/Business Layer]->[Data Layer]->[Sub-Data Layer*]->[JDBC]->[DBMS]` where the Sub-Data Layer is your "Linq" implementation. I say Linq, but it would really be more of your own "DBMS" implementation in your data layer.

Comment: As already mentioned **Apache Drill** does a unification of arbitrary datasources. Unfortunately and up to 1.2 it lacks stability and is not usable un a productive env.

Comment: @Craig: I wonder if I'm the first. Right now I'm thinking about implementing a custom JDBC driver that does query analysis, routes the queries acoordingly and gathers and assembles query results. gmiley: Maybe LINQ becomes in handy at that place ...

Comment: @MartinSenne Sounds like a fun 3-year project or a good thing to prototype for a PhD thesis ;)